# Converse of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem

Is the converse of the Chinese Remainder Theorem true? That is, *if*
$$(m, n)\neq1,$$
*then*
$$\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\ncong\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$$

Thanks.

Comment: @Arturo: I would normally phrase the CRT as "if $(m,n)=1$, then $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$", and using this formulation, the converse would be the statement "if $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}m\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then $(m,n)=1$", while the inverse is the statement in the question. Of course the inverse and converse are logically equivalent, so it does not matter too much; in fact I imagine "converse" is what most people who would want to find this post would search for.

Comment: @Zev: The statement here is contrapositive of the converse; I don't think I've never heard $\neg P\to \neg Q$ refered to as the "the inverse" of $P\to Q$, but that could just be my lack of familiarity.

Comment: @Arturo: I can indeed imagine it is not a universal term; and I myself would prefer to call it the contrapositive of the converse. But it is a term that I have heard before - and [here is the relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)). Again, it certainly doesn't change the real meaning, and moreover I think "converse" will be more helpful to people searching for this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The direct sum has no element of order $mn$.

Comment: And how about the generalisation of the Chinese remainder theorem in terms of rings? Could you please tell something about that?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \mathbb Z/m\: \oplus\: \mathbb Z/n\ $ has  *characteristic* $\rm\:lcm(m,n),\:$ which is $\rm\: < m\ n\ $ if $\rm\:\gcd(m,n) > 1\:.$