# If $R/I \times R/J$ is isomorphic to $R/(I\cap J)$ as $ R $-modules, then $I + J = R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

> If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $R/I \times R/J$ is isomorphic to $R/(I\cap J)$ as $R$-modules, then $I + J = R$.

I know this is the converse of CRT and there are many posts on this. However, I can't find a post that provides a complete answer to 
this.

This is the solution I found. 
[image]
However, I find it to be very complicated. What does $\otimes_R$ mean? What does tensor product mean? I have not learn tensor product.

**I prefer a solution without it and using only concepts from elementary ring theory course.**

Is there simpler answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Zorn's Lemma. The proof is quite elementary.

**Lemma 1.** If $A,B,C$ are $R$-modules such that $A \oplus B$ is cyclic, then every bilinear map $\beta : A \times B \to C$ is trivial.

*Proof.* Let $(u,v)$ be a generator of $A \oplus B$. Then $u$ is a generator of $A$ and $v$ is a generator of $B$. It suffices to prove $\beta(u,v)=0$. Choose some $r \in R$ such that $(u,0)=r(u,v)$. This means $u=ru$ and $rv=0$. Hence,
$$\beta(u,v) = \beta(ru,v)=\beta(u,rv)=\beta(u,0)=0. ~~~\checkmark$$

**Lemma 2.** For any two ideals $I,J \subseteq R$, there is a surjective bilinear map $$R/I \times R/J \to R/(I+J).$$

*Proof.* Just check that $(a \bmod I,b \bmod J) \mapsto a \cdot b \bmod I+J$ is well-defined, bilinear and surjective. $\checkmark$

**Corollary.** If $R/I \oplus R/J$ is cyclic, then $I+J=R$.

*Proof.* By Lemma 2, we have a surjective bilinear map $R/I \times R/J \to R/(I+J)$. By Lemma 1, it is trivial. Hence, by surjectivity, $R/(I+J)$ is trivial. This means $I+J=R$. $\checkmark$

---

The proof above is motivated by the following more usual proof, which uses universal objects (exterior powers and tensor products):

If $R/I \oplus R/J$ is cyclic, then

$0=\Lambda^2(R/I \oplus R/J)\\ ~~\cong \underbrace{\Lambda^2(R/I)}_{=0} \otimes \Lambda^0(R/J) \,\oplus\, \Lambda^1(R/I) \otimes \Lambda^1(R/J) \,\oplus\, \Lambda^0(R/I) \otimes \underbrace{\Lambda^2(R/J)}_{=0}\\ ~~ \cong R/I \otimes R/J\\ ~~ \cong R/(I+J). ~~~ \checkmark$

Comment: Why is $R/I \bigoplus R/J$ cyclic?

Comment: Why $\beta(u,0) = 0$? How is $\beta$ defined? Is bilinear map the same as normal mapping? Can you use ring homomorphism to explain this problem because this problem appears in my ring theory course and i don't really know what is bilinear map

Comment: $R/I \oplus R/J \cong R/(I \cap J)$ is cyclic (=generated by one element). The notion of a bilinear map is elementary, just look it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map

Comment: "Another" elementary answer can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244165/121097).

Comment: Essentially it's the same argument, without the structure of my answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg why being isomorphic to $R/I \cap J$ means it is cyclic? I thought cyclic means it can be written as Rm for some m?